# .resample('W') picks one column only while subset includes two columns

Tags: python, pandas, summarize

I am trying to resample a Pandas dataframe after subsetting for 2 columns. Below is the head of the dataframe. Both columns are Pandas Series.

```
temp_2011_clean[['visibility', 'dry_bulb_faren']].head()
                    visibility  dry_bulb_faren
2011-01-01 00:53:00     10.00   51.0
2011-01-01 01:53:00     10.00   51.0
2011-01-01 02:53:00     10.00   51.0
2011-01-01 03:53:00     10.00   50.0
2011-01-01 04:53:00     10.00   50.0

type(temp_2011_clean['visibility'])
pandas.core.series.Series

type(temp_2011_clean['dry_bulb_faren'])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

While the .resample('W') method successfully creates the resample object, if I chain the .mean() method to the same, it is picking up only one column, instead of the expected, both columns. Can someone suggest what could be the issue? Why is that one column is missed?

```
temp_2011_clean[['visibility', 'dry_bulb_faren']].resample('W')
<pandas.core.resample.DatetimeIndexResampler object at 0x0000016F4B943288>

temp_2011_clean[['visibility', 'dry_bulb_faren']].resample('W').mean().head()
            dry_bulb_faren
2011-01-02  44.791667
2011-01-09  50.246637
2011-01-16  41.103774
2011-01-23  47.194313
2011-01-30  53.486188
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem should be column `visibility` is not numeric, so non numeric column is excluded.

```
print (temp_2011_clean.dtypes)
visibility         object
dry_bulb_faren    float64
dtype: object

df = temp_2011_clean[['visibility', 'dry_bulb_faren']].resample('W').mean()
print (df)
            dry_bulb_faren
2011-01-02            50.6
```

So convert column to numeric by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert non numeric values to `NaN`s:

```
temp_2011_clean['visibility'] = pd.to_numeric(temp_2011_clean['visibility'], errors='coerce')

print (temp_2011_clean.dtypes)
visibility        float64
dry_bulb_faren    float64
dtype: object

df = temp_2011_clean[['visibility', 'dry_bulb_faren']].resample('W').mean()
print (df)
            visibility  dry_bulb_faren
2011-01-02        10.0            50.6
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, you are absolutely right. Thanks a lot. Just want to know. In order to reproduce a solution/ analysis example, as you did above, do you reconstruct a similar dataframe and other objects? What is the usual process adopted by responders?

Comment: @Srinivas - I use `temp_2011_clean['visibility'] = temp_2011_clean['visibility'].astype(str)`  ;)